# Existence of a surjective map that is not the quotient map by the action of a group of homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

I found the following exercise: there exist two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ and a continuous, surjective map $f: X \to Y$ such that $f$ is not obtained as the quotient map by the action of a group of homeomorphisms?

In the comments, it has been answered me to take $X=Y=\{1,2\}$ with respectively the discrete and the indiscrete topology. Why? Can you provide me another detailed less trivial example, please? I thought the projection $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2/D$, where $D$ is the unit disk. If I'm wrong, what is the reason?

Comment: $X = \{1,2\}$ with discrete topology, $Y = \{1,2\}$ with indiscrete topology, $f = \mathrm{id}$?

Comment: Can you show that $f$ is not the quotient map by the action of a group of homeomorphisms?

Comment: That is obvious considering what $X$ is. I would be more worried that this example is not interesting enough.